# How to test whether an identifier that is accessible only through a #define macro is defined?

Tags: c++, c, macros

I have a #define mapping an identifier (a function name) to a new name like this:

```
#define A doStuff
```

This part I cannot do anything about, I have to access "A" since the actual identifier (doStuff here) may change (and this is not under my control). Now the referenced symbol (doStuff) may or may not exist, and I want to invoke the function in the former case. For a plain function name I can test this easily:

```
#ifdef doStuff
    doStuff();
#endif
```

However, being restricted to the macro name, doing the same naively would be:

```
#ifdef A
    A();
#endif
```

which gives an error since the name "A" is defined, while "doStuff" is not. I'd like to check the existence of the name the macro resolves into, essentially:

```
#if defined(the-content-of-A)
```

but I cannot make it work.

So my question: is there any way to check whether an identifier represented by a macro is defined? If yes, how to do it? If no, is there a common pattern for a workaround?

Although I don't think that this is either C or C++ specific I'd like to note that I need something that works for an identifier defined "extern C" in C++. The solution must be platform independent.

Sorry if this was asked before, I could not find it, neither with google nor on SO.

Comment: Please note that your example with `#ifdef doStuff` is wrong. You cannot detect presence of C/C++ functions at preprocessor level. Moreover, do you want to recognize `#define A` (i.e. `A` exists but has no value) or `#define A unavailable-function`?

Comment: If the target function doesn't exist, `A` should not be defined at all. Then you can detect the case with `#ifdef`.

Comment: As many people answered, you can't change behavior due to function existence in the preprocessor. But you can do that with template meta-programming, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence

Comment: Thanks for the clarificartion. It is well possible that the symbol which I called doStuff in the question in actually a macro in the real code.

Comment: All answers are to the spot, but I can accept only one. Thanks also to the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining identifiers (functions, objects) is something that happens *after* the preprocessing, so you can not possibly determine during preprocessing whether a function will be defined later.

What you can do as workaround is that you always define a macro alongside with the function:

```
void A();
#define A_SUPPLIED
```

and then test against that:

```
#ifdef A_SUPPLIED
...
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, no.

I think your real problem is that you don't understand the difference between macros (introduced to the preprocessor using `#define` and expanded using text substitution before the result is actually compiled in a later phase of compilation) and identifiers (which are compile time constructs that cannot be tested for by the preprocessor).

I say this because the only way

```
#ifdef doStuff
    doStuff();
#endif
```

will work as you claim is if `doStuff()` is a macro.   It will not work if doStuff() is an identifier (for example, the name of a function or variable).

For example, in C++

```
#include <iostream>

void doStuff() {std::cout << "Hello\n";}

int main()
{
    #ifdef doStuff
        doStuff();
    #else
        std::cout << "Bye\n";
    #endif
}
```

will print `Bye` rather than `Hello`.   That is because a function definition does not produce a macro, and is not detected by `#ifdef`.

About the only way is to define a macro as a companion to the function

```
 void DoStuff();
 #define DoStuff_DEFINED

 #ifdef DoStuff_Defined
     DoStuff();
 #else
     ComplainBitterly();     /*   assumes ComplainBitterly() exists of DoStuff_DEFINED is not defined */
 #endif
```

Comment: Thanks. It is well possible that the symbol which I called doStuff in the question in actually a macro in the real code.

Comment: If it is a macro, it can be tested for using the preprocessor.   But it is not an identifier or a "symbol".

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to determine whether an identifier exists in pure C, with or without the macro (your `#ifdef doStuff` example doesn't actually work). This is because at macro expansion time, the compiler's just doing text substitution; it doesn't know what symbols are defined. The ideal approach would be for your library header to expose an `A_IS_PRESENT` macro or similar you can `#ifdef` off of here.

However, if that's not an option, it may be possible with platform-specific extensions. On Linux, for example, you can define a weak symbol, then determine whether it is overridden by the real deal:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
// Define a dummy function; if A is not present we will make A an alias of this
int A_surrogate() {}
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

// The alias attribute makes 'A' equivalent to 'A_surrogate'. The weak attribute
// means that if some other definition exists, that one takes precedence.
int __attribute__((weak, alias("A_surrogate"))) A();

int is_A_present() {
  // Was A in fact overridden?
  return &A != &A_surrogate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint at the Linux solution, but that won't do it in my case.